# How to overlay two audio with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, overlay

Im trying mix two audio with these codes:

```
for %a in ("audio\*.mp3") do ffmpeg -y -i "%a" -i "background\back.mp3" -filter_complex "[0:0]volume=1[a];[1:0]volume=0.1[b];[a][b]amix=inputs=2:duration=first" "source\%~na.mp3"
```

my "back.mp3" is short and i need it repeats until the first mp3 file ends.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ffmpeg 4.1 or newer, you can use stream_loop.

`for %a in ("audio\*.mp3") do ffmpeg -y -i "%a" -stream_loop -1 -i "background\back.mp3" -filter_complex "[0:0]volume=1[a];[1:0]volume=0.1[b];[a][b]amix=inputs=2:duration=first" "source\%~na.mp3"`